# Editing the a specific string in a file?

Tags: java

So I am creating a program which when called, will have input, go to a file and change the number assigned to the string called. For example:

The file would look like:

```
stone 0 wood 5 water 2 metal 5
```

and if "wood" was called, it would go into the file, find wood then send add one to the value to the right of wood, which would only change that value to 6, then saves the file.

I've looked around on the internet but couldn't really find much which is tailored to my specific problem. Its either changing an int to either one or the other, or changing all ints to something.

```java
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FileWriter fw;
        BufferedReader reader;
        StringBuffer ib;

        String allBlockAndNull = "stone 0 wood 5 water 2 metal 5";

        String strDir = "C:\\Users\\amdro\\Desktop\\test.txt";
        File fileDir = new File(strDir);

        //creates file it doesn't exist
        try {
            fw = new FileWriter(fileDir);
            fw.write(allBlockAndNull);

            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {}

    }
}
```

If you could expand from the above, that would be great!

Comment: Most of the time you won't find solutions online specifically tailored for your problem. It often involves some coding of your own to tailor general best-practice approaches to what you actually need. Can you show us what you have tried to get the input and actually change the value?

Comment: Can you show the output , how you want

Comment: There is not any "ready" solution to your problem. You should probably combine some "String" methods. For example you can find index of "wood" and after that you will be able to get the number assigned to that. Increase that number and place at previous index. It is first thing that come to my head, but if you think a bit and make some tries you probably will find better solution.

Comment: you can read the entire file, change the string and write it back...

Comment: It seems as if your actual question is not how to read and write the file (your code snippet indicates you're able to do that) but how to find the correct value to replace. One solution could be to split the input at whitespace, build a `LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>` so as to preserve the order of the elements (parse the numbers to `Integer`), find the correct entry and increment its value and finally write the entries back to a file (or to a string first).

Answer (score 1):

This is a very **simple** and **basic** solution to your problem: It consists of reading the file, appending all changes to a string and overwriting the same file with the string.

Create a scanner to read your text file and initialise a new string variable

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("fileName.txt"));
String line = "";
```

While there is still a character in the text file, get the `word` and the `number`

```
while(sc.hasNext()){
    String word = s.next();
    int number = s.nextInt();
```

Then, inside the `while` loop, use `switch` and `case` to check the word. For example, if word = "wood", append "wood" and the new number, `newNumber` to `line`

```
case "wood":
    line += word + " " + newNumber + " ";
    break;
```

The default will be appending the word and the old number, `number`

```
default:
    line += word + " " + number + " ";
```

Finally, just create a `FileWriter` and a `BufferedWriter` to write `line` to the text file.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add numbers to a value from a file because all the values are Strings but what you can do is replace the String value

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                File file = new File("file.txt");//The file containing stone 0 wood 5 water 2 metal 5
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                String words = "", list = "";

                while ((words = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    list += words;
                }
                reader.close();
                Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
                if(list.contains("wood")) {
                String replacedtext = list.replaceAll("wood 5", "wood 6");

                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.txt");
                writer.write(replacedtext);
                writer.close();
                }
            }
        }
```